# Lots of Fun with Doctrine ORM and Silex - Doctrine MappingException: Class does not exist

Tags: doctrine-orm, silex

I am using the DflyDevDoctrineORMServicProvider with Silex. I have created a simple model as a proof of concept.

I am able to build the model (PHP classes) from my Yml files- but when I try to generate the schema, and populate the database etc - it all falls apart, and I get the error message:

```
[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]  
  Class 'DistrictType' does not exist
```

I must admit, I am struggling with PHP Namespaces and how they relate to Doctrine Mappings and file locations - I'm sure the problem is likely to be related to this confusion.

I will briefly describe my directory layout and the configuration files I am using - hopefully, someone maybe able to spot where I am going wrong:

**Directory layout**

```
|
|---src
|   app.php           // app variable cration, autoloading etc ..
|   registration.php  // service registration etc ..
|---Entity            // Generated models go here
|---Resources
|   |-- mappings      // YamL model definitions here ...
|
|---config
|   cli-config.php
|   config.yml
|
|---web               
    index.php         // imports app.php
    composer.json
    .htaccess
```

**Snippet from registration.php**

```
$app->register(new DoctrineOrmServiceProvider, array(
            "orm.proxies_dir" => __DIR__.'/../cache/doctrine/proxy',
                "orm.em.options" => array(
                        "mappings" => array(
                            // Using actual filesystem paths
                            array(
                                   "type" => "yml",
                                   "namespace" => "Entity",
                                   "path" => __DIR__."/Resources/mappings"
                                ),  
                         ),  
                     ),  
             )); 

// Setup entity manager (Possible Hack)
$paths = array($app['orm.em.options']['mappings'][0]['path']);
$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration($paths, $app['debug']);
$app['orm.em'] = EntityManager::create($app['db.options'], $config);
```

**cli-config.php**

```
<?php

// ...

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../src/app.php';

$isDevMode = $app['debug'];

$paths = array($app['orm.em.options']['mappings'][0]['path']);
$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($app['db.options'], $config);

$commands = array(
            new \UseAllFive\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand(),
    );

return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($entityManager);
```

Now here are the models:

**District.dcm.yml**

```
District:
    type: entity
    table: pac_district
    repositoryClass: DistrictRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:        
        name:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false

    manyToOne:
        region:
            targetEntity: Region
            joinColumn:
                name: region_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete: RESTRICT
                onUpdate: CASCADE

        district_type:
            targetEntity: DistrictType
            joinColumn:
                name: district_type_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                onDelete: RESTRICT
                onUpdate: CASCADE
    uniqueConstraints:
        uidx_district_name:
            columns: [name]
```

**DistrictType.dcm.yml**

```
DistrictType:
    type: entity
    table: pac_district_type
    repositoryClass: DistrictTypeRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:        
        name:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false

    uniqueConstraints:
        uidx_district_type_name:
            columns: [name]
```

**Region.dcm.yml**

```
Region:                             
    type: entity
    table: pac_region       
    repositoryClass: RegionRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:        
        name:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false

    uniqueConstraints:
        uidx_region_name:
            columns: [name]
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": { 
        "silex/silex": "2.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.6.7",
        "doctrine/dbal": "~2.2",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.1",
        "dflydev/doctrine-orm-service-provider": "2.0.*@dev"
    },  
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"Controller": "src/"}, 
        "psr-0": {"Entity": "src/"} 
    }   
}
```

These are the results of the following commands:

```
root@yourbox:~/path/to/project$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities src/Entity/
Processing entity "Region"
Processing entity "DistrictType"
Processing entity "District"

Entity classes generated to "/path/to/project/src/Entity"


root@yourbox:~/path/to/project$ vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create

  [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]  
  Class 'DistrictType' does not exist
```

I have struggled with this for two days straight - and can't see what I'm doing wrong - can anyone spot what Imay be doing wrong?

Comment: could you show us generated-entity code?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple actually. What you are doing wrong is - autoloading files. The way your composer file is configured now, it will not autoload the entity files and the schema creation will fail.

Modify your composer autoload section by passing an empty string as first parameter, and add `Entity` to the path, like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"Controller": "src/"}, 
    "psr-0": {"": "src/Entity/"} 
}
```

Then run `composer update` and you would be able to generate your entities. On a side note, currently I am developing a small project with Silex as well, and I would strongly recommend you switch to using Namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Artamiel that fixed my problem, it was a combination of adding the autoload in composer and fixing the namespace, I mean my autoload now has:

```
"psr-0": {"Entity": "config/doctrine/"}
```

And as I have defined the namespace as Entity created such a folder and move the entities there, and finally I am up and running. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't answer with another answer but a comment. Also if @Artamiel helped, play nice and [accept his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I can not comment on his answer or accept it, i woukd like to but i can. His answer help me a lot so i wanted to thank him

Comment: My bad, I thought you were the OP, I see you're not, sorry! (also you've too little rep. for comments, next time I'll stay quiet, I promise :-)